# Can we do soql or sosl query on Salesforce Labels

Tags: soql, sosl

how to query salesforce Labels using SOQL OR SOSL  in query editor.

Comment: Custom labels are not accessible via SOQL. You will need to use the Metadata API to complete the query you are looking for.

Comment: My biggest question is why do you want to query them? What do you want to do with them once you've queried them? And where are you accessing them from (Apex or integration)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a SOQL/SOSL query on them  but you can access the Labels by using `Label.LabelName`.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with what is being asked here.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the custom label using SOQL like in the Developer console: SELECT Id, Name from customlabel where name='LabelName'.
Make sure you have checked 'Use Tooling API'

[[image]][1**]**

Comment: From API perspective , same above can be fetched with SOQL at endpoint  like : 
`https://<OrgUrl>/services/data/v48.0/tooling/query/?q=select%20Id%2C%20Name%20from%20Customlabel%0Awhere%20Name%20%3D%20%27LabelName%27`